# ruby enterprise and Rails<3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-enterprise-edition

i'm trying to run Redmine using rubyEE, but I am constantly facing some action_controller problems.
When I'm running unicorn, I get:

```
/opt/rubyEE-2010-02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:223:in `activate': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /opt/rubyEE-2010-02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:34
        from /opt/rubyEE-2010-02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /opt/rubyEE-2010-02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
```

When I remove the vendor directory I get:

```
# unicorn_rails -c /etc/redmine.ru -E production
I, [2010-12-19T20:52:36.251056 #21117]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:4000 fd=3
I, [2010-12-19T20:52:36.253061 #21117]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

However, I have those gems installed:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.9, 2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.9, 2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.9, 2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.9, 2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.9, 2.3.5)
arel (2.0.4)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7)
daemon_controller (0.2.5)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
i18n (0.4.2)
kgio (2.0.0)
mail (2.2.10)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql (2.8.1)
passenger (3.0.0)
pg (0.9.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (2.3.9, 2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rubytree (0.8.1)
spruz (0.2.2)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
unicorn (3.1.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to remove rails 2.3.9, they might be get loaded because of no strict dependencies:

```
gem uninstall actionpack activesupport -v 2.3.9
```

If you need both versions you can use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) for more ruby versions easy configurable per project.